# How to get data when we provide multiple value of a field

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 id in a string:

```
  let $x="6,3,5"
```

I want to get  all color information from `tbl_color` where color `id` are

6, 3 and 5.

I made this query, but does not work. What's wrong with this?

```
$sql=" SELECT * FROM tbl_color WHERE color_id IN(".explode(',',$x).")
```

please suggest the right query

Comment: what do i do Mr AJ, some of my questions have no right and satisfactory answer then how do i accept them? m i wrong?

Comment: @ILP, if there is no right answer then I would suggest either set a bounty or edit/revise your original question.  ooc, did my answer help this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[explode()](http://php.net/explode) takes a string and turns it into an array.  You already have a string.  All you need to do is change your statement and just include $x in your string.  You don't need to explode it.

---

UPDATE:

Per your comment, here is how I would do it:

```
$x="3,4,5";
$sql=" SELECT * FROM tbl_color WHERE color_id IN(".$x.");";
```

HTH,

-aj

Comment: i need all data from tbl_color  where color id is 3 and 4 and 5 then wahta will be exact query, please write down sir

Comment: How can an ID be 3, 4, and 5 at the same time?

Comment: not same time sir, i means i got id lists from another query, now i want to find all color name and decriprion of these ids

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating an array with a string. The explode is not needed:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_color WHERE color_id IN ($x)";
```

A full example assuming you get the input from a user or it is sent from the browser to the server:

```
$x = $_GET['colors']; // 6,3,5
$x = mysql_real_escape_string( $x ); // Prevent SQL Injection attack
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_color WHERE color_id IN ($x)";
```

Answer (score 0):

If $x is a string, then you don't need to use explode, just use it *as is*

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM tbl_color WHERE color_id IN($x)";
```